# NGINX Set header only if upstream responds with a custom header

Tags: http, nginx, cookies, header

I have a upstream server that sets a `Session-ID` header only on some requests. I want to forward that session id in a cookie.

I tried something like this.

```
add_header   Set-Cookie "session_id=$sent_http_session_id;";
```

This works for request where the upstream server sets the header, but for requests where there is no header present, this results in the following HTTP header: `Set-Cookie: session_id=;`, which overwrites the correct cookie.

I tried with an `if` but **that did not work**:

```
if ($sent_http_session_id) {
    add_header   Set-Cookie "session_id=$sent_http_session_id";
}
```

How can I set an header only if the upstream responds with a custom header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling (we even looked on page 2 :P) we found a solution:

This works with a `map`, where `$sent_http_session_id` refers to the header that we want to map (see [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_sent_http_)):

```
map $sent_http_session_id $header_to_cookie {
    ""  "";                                     # No header results in no cookie
    default "session_id=$sent_http_session_id"; # Mapping from custom header to cookie
}

server{
    # ...
    
    location / {
        # ... 
        add_header                  Set-Cookie $header_to_cookie;
    }
}
```